# Фирма для клиента и админа

Tags: python, aiogram

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать фильтр для команды. Пример если команду пишет обычный пользователь бот выдаёт ошибку "ты не админ ", а если команду пишет админ выполняем.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поставить проверку user_id(каждый пользователь имеет свой юзер айди):

```
#глобальная переменная с вашим айди
myId = 'ваш айди'
...
if str(message.from_user.id) == myId:
#код выполняемый если вы админ
else:
    #код выполняемый если вы не админ
```